# Bootstrap - Fix Div to bottom of div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a div, and in that div, I have another div. I am trying to pin the inner div to the bottom of the outer div using specifically bootstrap classes, but I cant seem to find a bootstrap method to do this. I've also tried using just regular CSS, but cant get this working. I tried veritical-align: bottom; and setting the position to absolute.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card-body">
  <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4" style="text-align: left;">
    <li>stuff</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also been searching SO, but cant find a question related to fixing a div to the bottom of a div.

Comment: sound confuse.. why not u just re-position of html element to archive the result

Answer (score 3):

To get it done using Bootstrap 4 classes, you just add the classes `d-flex flex-column` to the `card-body` and then add the `mt-auto` class (margin-top:auto) to the inner div like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
    <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4" style="text-align: left;">
        <li>stuff</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mt-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

That will always keep the inner div pinned to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve??

```css
.card-body {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  border: 4px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card-body">
  <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4" style="text-align: left;">
    <li>stuff</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="inner">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```